# Matching characters in different range of values

Tags: regex

I want to make sure my regex match any number from `0-9`, any word from `a-z`, and any of the following characteristics `@#$&*:";?!` irrespective of when its position in a word or sentence.
If I have `ab$2ww3&#` my regex will give a positive result but if I have `@#he&+#shsj` it won't work because there is no number or `jbsb2727hd3d` won't work because the specific characters I need is not present.
Please I need help on this

Comment: Please show your regexp that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the characters you want to match inside a single character class.

```
[0-9a-z@#$&*:";?!]
```

```js
let input = "asyeb336sheh33";
if (/[0-9a-z@#$&*:";?!]/.test(input)) {
  console.log('matched');
}

input = "dhd27shs3hj7";
if (/[0-9a-z@#$&*:";?!]/.test(input)) {
  console.log('matched');
}

input = "@#he&+#shsj";
if (/[0-9a-z@#$&*:";?!]/.test(input)) {
  console.log('matched');
}
```